# How to make the external host IP address assigned to container hostname?

Tags: docker

Except the --net=host, is there any method to make the container's hostname are bind to the external host IP address?

My projects need the feature of port-forwarding a lot, and quite some containers are on same node. So --net=host doesn't meed my requirements.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. What happens when you have two containers on the same host? They can't both have the same IP address.

Comment: they can. ip:port. I will assign port number dynamically to containers on same node.

Comment: I can achieve this before docker v1.12 by using extra_hosts and an env HOSTNAME passed into docker. But now, this method doesn't work. So I want to figure out still in the similiar way.

Answer (score 0):

The `-p hostport:containerport` option is made for this purpose. If you want use the same host IP in the same port for different applications like Apache virtual hosts. I recommend using an apache or nginx container which will do the reverse proxy using hostnames

Regards

Comment: yep, this could be a way. But I can achieve this before docker v1.12 by using extra_hosts and an env HOSTNAME passed into docker. But now, this method doesn't work. So I want to figure out still in the similiar way, while not entire alternative solution. Thanks anyway.